# what does mean this number in react devTools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, profiler, react-devtools

I have a Nextjs app that I want to profile for performance issues.

Im using the react dev tool profiler in chrome

I profile a specific interaction and get the flamegraph and the ranked time graph in the dev tool.

Then this message shows up in the dev tool:

```
Why did this render?
- Hooks 1,7 and 15 changed
```

This part of the dev tool is not interactive, and I cant find anything on how the hooks are numbered.

How do I interpret these numbers? What do they correspond to? Where can I find the information on what hooks they refer?

Comment: also trying to figure this out, were you able to figure anything out about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in this StackOverflow Post: [What does the hook numbers in the Reactjs Dev tool correspond to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68925790/what-does-the-hook-numbers-in-the-reactjs-dev-tool-correspond-to)

As per this React [Pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/20998), the numbers correspond to those shown in the Components tab:
[image: Components Tab]