# When react outputs "Hook 2 and 3 changed" in the profiler, is it the order in which they're called?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When using the profiler from the React Dev Tools extension, in the tab that says *"Why did this render?"* and it shows the number of the hooks that changed, is this the same as the order in which they are defined/called in the component?

For example:

[image: Hook Changed]

Then in my component:

```js
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);
const [bar, setBar] = useState(0);
const [baz, setBaz] = useState(0);
```

Does it correspond to the second hook and third hook, `bar` and `baz`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69263985/17099285

If that link stops working the gist of it is: "that if you want to find the hook you must go to the components tab in dev tools and inspect said component; in the hooks section, you'll have a tree of the called hooks, and for each hook, a small number at the left which is the index. You'll probably need to unfold the tree of hooks to find them."