# Reactjs dev tool: hook number does not exist

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In order to understand why components are re-renders without apparent reason, I started the profiler. I can see that my component re-renders because of `Hook 18`:

[image]

So to understand what this mean, I tried to follow the advice in this question [What does the hook numbers in the Reactjs Dev tool correspond to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68925790/what-does-the-hook-numbers-in-the-reactjs-dev-tool-correspond-to) that basically says that hooks are listed in the corresponding component tab. So I went there… but my hook is not listed here: the maximum hook is 15, not 18!

[image]

Any idea what I’m missing? I’m sure that I selected the right component as both times the same component is highlighted.

Comment: Recently ran into this issue today too. Did they perhaps push a fault update to the React debugging tools?

Comment: @ShreyGupta Oh interesting, we should try to fill a bug then. By any chance is your example simple enough to submit it right away?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: @cr4z No… If you can get a simple enough MWE, you can fill a bug online and let us know.

Comment: Did you fill an issue? Can you provide the link to it.

Comment: No, I never took the time to extract a mirimal working exemple needed to create an issue. Feel free to do one.